# I have an error displayed called: error: expected expression and I don't know what's the ide expecting

Tags: c, cs50

My code goes as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main (void)
{
    string name = get_string("What's your name? ");
    int age = get_int("What's your age? ");
    int phone = get_int("what's your phone number? ");
    do
    {
    char answer = get_char("Are the information bellow correct? (y or n): \n Name: %s \n Age: %i \n Phone: %i", name, age, phone);
    }
    while (char answer = y | char answer = n);

}
```

the error is in line 13 `while (char answer = y || char answer = n);` for "expected expression". Anyone knows what should I do in this case? I also would appreciate a feedback on the way I wrote line 13, is that the correct way to get either one of the characters I'm looking for?

Comment: You have not defined variables `y` and `n` and `=` is an assignment, not a comparison. The syntax and logic are skewed too. Try `while (answer != 'y' && answer != 'n');`

Comment: you don't put variable declarations inside the `while()` condition.

Comment: `char answer = y | char answer = n` should be `answer != 'y' && answer != 'n'` And you need to define the `answer` variable *before* the loop. Please take some time to go back and review the course sections about variable life-time and scope, comparisons, conditions, and literals.

Comment: `answer` is out of scope in the`while()` test. You'll need to declare it outside the loop.

Comment: OT: please realise that phone "numbers", card "numbers" etc are not integers. They are strings. Input and store the phone number as a string.

Comment: ... and your `int phone` probably won't even hold my 11-digit phone number (and will lose the leading zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues:

- PROBLEM: "y" and "n" weren't defined as variables, hence the compile error.

  SOLUTION: Use [character literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) instead
- Use "||" and "&&" for "conditionals" ([logical operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical)), and use "|" and "&" for "boolean arithmetic".
- You declared variable "answer" locally, inside your "do{}" block. You should declare it *OUTSIDE* the braces.

EXAMPLE:

```
char answer;
do {
    answer = get_char("Is the information below correct? (y or n): \n Name: %s \n Age: %i \n Phone: %i", name, age, phone);
} while (answer != 'y' && answer != 'n');
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your `answer` before the `do-while` loop. If it is in the body (`{}`) of the loop, you can't access it from the condition you need for the `while` since it gets destroyed at the end of the block it is in (at the `}`).

Further, to mark something as a character you need to put it in `''` like `'y'`/`'n'`, otherwise C will look for a variable named `y`/`n`, which does not exist and you use the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==`.

In your code you use a single `|` but in the text two `||` for the or in the condition for `while()`. The `|` is a bit or, the `||` is a logical or which you would want to use here. However your loop would run as long as the user inputs either `y` or `n`, which is probably not the result you want to get. To get the loop running until the user writes `y` or `n` you could use a logical not `!`, which inverts the result of a Boolean expression like this: `while (!(answer == 'y' || answer == 'n'));`. There are multiple ways you could write your expression as you can see in the comments on your question or in @paulsm4's answer.

A functional solution could look like this:

```
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    string name = get_string("What's your name? ");
    int age = get_int("What's your age? ");
    int phone = get_int("what's your phone number? ");
    char answer;
    do
    {
        answer = get_char("Are the information bellow correct? (y or n): \n Name: %s \n Age: %i \n Phone: %i", name, age, phone);
    } while (!(answer == 'y' || answer == 'n'));
}
```